# Linking URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I yesterday created a website with functional searchbar. But my problem with it is, I coded it in JavaScript, and I don't know how to link URL on click to button. https://apex-lang.github.io is my website, check out "Search destination" searchbox to see what I mean. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
const ac = document.querySelector('.autocomplete');

M.Autocomplete.init(ac, {

    data: {
        "Aruba": null,
        "Cancun Mexico": null,
        "Hawaii": null,
        "Florida": null,
        "California": null,
        "Jamacia": null,
        "Europe": null,
        "Bahamas": null,
        "Nova Scotia": null,
        "Rialto": null,
    }
});
```

I used MaterializeCSS framework to make this website.

```
<!-- Section: Search -->
<section id="search" class="section section-search teal darken-1 white-text center scrollspy">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <h3>Search Destinations</h3>
                <div class="input-field">
                    <input class="white grey-text autocomplete" placeholder="Aruba, Cancun, etc..." type="text" id="autocomplete-input">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This is my HTML Code

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more code.

Comment: Have you tried using an `a` tag?

Comment: Heretic Monkey, i tried but it would not work

Comment: ControlAltDel In JavaScrcipt?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input id="age">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(a) {
a = document.getElementById("age").value;
if (a == "Aruba") {window.open("your link")}
else if (a == "Another country") {window.open("your link")}}
</script>
```

This works

Comment: I don't need search engine,I just want to,when clicked on any place,goes to the URL which i linked

Comment: So basically you want that for example if I write "Aruba" then, it links to a page?

Comment: If You write, for example "Aruba" and click on it, it links to a page

Comment: I edited my previous answer (you have to go where it is written  "here is the answer:")

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add an onclick function to the list that MaterializeCSS creates (class .autocomplete-content)

Then you can get the target of the click with event.target, then you have access to its properties

for example

```js
document
  .querySelector(".autocomplete-content")
  .addEventListener(
    "click", 
    e => {
      var item= e.target
      // what to do on each click
      console.log(item.innerHTML)
    }
  )
```

tested directly on your site it gives me `<span class="highlight">Can</span>cun Mexico`

### [edit] a more complete example

for your site to redirect to the page 'https://apex-lang.github.io/cancun' when clicking to cancun and to 'https://apex-lang.github.io/aruba' when wlicking on aruba :

```js
// first declare a dictionnary with key = text of the item and value = url
var redirections = {
  "Aruba": "https://apex-lang.github.io/aruba",
  "Cancun Mexico": "https://apex-lang.github.io/cancun"
  // add all the items here
  // be sure the text is the exact same as in the list given to Autocomplete
}

document
  .querySelector(".autocomplete-content")
  .addEventListener(
    "click", 
    e => {
      var item= e.target

      var destination = item.innerText 
      // only gets the visible text without the tags
      window.location = redirections[destination] // redirects the page to the URL
    }
  )
```

Comment: Eh sir,I don't really understand what do you mean.Can you please explain it better?

Comment: if you want your website to do something as soon as you click on an item of the list, you need to do that thing where `// what to do on each click` is. But a better solution would be to add a button on the side of your **input** then have the button redirect your user when clicked, depending on the `document.querySelector('.autocomplete').value`